# App/webapp to play tracks and help remember pop music genres

Tags: music

Can you recognize [Rocksteady](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocksteady), [Reggaeton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reggaeton), [Raga](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Raga), [Mandopop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandopop), [Dubtronica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubtronica)?

I am looking for an app/webapp that would play me tracks of various genres.

The user interface would show me a "Show genre" button. I would think in my head *(for instance: "hmm sounds like [Dangdut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangdut))* and press "Show genre" to reveal the answer. Based on whether I was right or wrong, I am able to rate myself, and this data is used to play me more tracks of this genre over the day. Similar to the [concept of Anki and other SRS apps](http://ankisrs.net/docs/manual.html#spaced-repetition).

If I don't press "Show genre" before the end of the track, the next track starts playing immediately. It continues playing tracks all day, concentrating on the genres whose name I tend to forget.

- Free
- YouTube-based mashups are OK
- a few hundred genres, for instance [those](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_popular_music_genres)